# saving information that does not need to be registered

Tags: java

Each line in the txt file stores information about a village. For example, the level of the village, the number of villagers in it...
The loadVillage method reads a line and puts informations in the village object.

```
    lines = readFile("/Data/villages.txt");
    Village village;
    x = 0;
    village = loadVillage(lines.get(x));
    village.setLocation(44, 28);
    villages.add(village);
    x++;        
    village = loadVillage(lines.get(x));
    village.setLocation(48, 328);
    villages.add(village);
    x++;
    village = loadVillage(lines.get(x));
    village.setLocation(864, 136);
    villages.add(village);
    x++;
    village = loadVillage(lines.get(x));
    village.setLocation(808, 628);
    villages.add(village);
    x++;
    village = loadVillage(lines.get(x));
    village.setLocation(104, 984);
    villages.add(village);
    x++;
```

My question is:
I set the locations of the village as you can see in the code. Would it make sense to read this location information from the txt file as well? So I can shorten the code as follows:

```
lines = readFile("/Data/villages.txt");
for(String line: lines) {
    villages.add(loadVillage(line));
}
```

So I don't need to save it in a txt file since the location information is not a changing information. Also, if I save extra information, it takes longer to read. which one should i do?

Comment: The time taken to read a few extra lines will not slow down your application in any way unless you have thousands of villages. It's really just a personal preference on which method you want to use, but whatever you do, don't put the information in two places.

Comment: Okay thanks so I guess I will read the village locations from the txt file. By putting the information in two places, do you mean putting the same information in two places? Or splitting multiple pieces of different information about the same object into two places?

Comment: Either put it in code or in the text file, but not both. We do this to prevent confusion and remove unnecessary code/text.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand again. do you mean that if we are pulling information from the txt file, we should also read from the txt file all other information that does not need to be saved?

Comment: Yes, only put information in the file if you will use it, otherwise there is no point and it will be confusing.